# Windows Chrome extension native messaging can only receive the first response

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to use native messaging to send some data to my native windows application. It works well with the runtime.sendNativeMessage() method. When I am trying to use long lived connections which uses a port, it also can pass data from chrome to my app. However,  chrome extension can only receive the first response from my app. I am sure that the port is still open because my app can still receive data from chrome. Following are my code:

Chrome Extension Script:

```js
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.mydomain.app1');

port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("Received from port:", msg);
});

port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
    console.log("Disconnected");
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {  
        var param = {};
        param['url'] = tab.url; 
        port.postMessage( param);   
    }
}
```

My windows app in c++:

```cpp
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while( true )
    {
         //read the first four bytes (=> Length)
         unsigned int length = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
              char c;
              if( ( c=getchar()) != EOF) 
                  length += c<<i*8;
              else return 0;
          }

          //read the json-message
          std::string msg = "";
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
          {
              msg += getchar();
          } 

          //.... do something

          //send a response message
          std::string message = "{\"text\": \"This is a response message\"}";
          unsigned int len = message.length();
          // We need to send the 4 bytes of length information
          std::cout << char(((len>>0) & 0xFF))
                    << char(((len>>8) & 0xFF))
                    << char(((len>>16) & 0xFF))
                    << char(((len>>24) & 0xFF));
           // Now we can output our message
           std::cout << message.c_str();
           std::cout.flush();
          
     }
}
```

Notice that the last line "**std::cout.flush();**", if I comment it out, even the first response won't be shown in chrome. I just couldn't figure out how chrome reads from the app's stdout.

Comment: Just a correction: the above code is actually working. My actually  code contains some preparation for the response message. That is where the problem is. Please check my comment on Almog's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with automatic flushing - `std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::unitbuf )`

Also, the way you read/write the input/output messages length is incorrect and will fail on long messages.

This code works well for me:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::unitbuf );

    while (true)
    {
        unsigned int ch, inMsgLen = 0, outMsgLen = 0;
        std::string input = "", response = "";

        // Read 4 bytes for data length
        std::cin.read((char*)&inMsgLen, 4);

        if (inMsgLen == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Loop getchar to pull in the message until we reach the total length provided.
            for (int i=0; i < inMsgLen; i++)
            {
                ch = getchar();
                input += ch;
            }
        }

        response.append("{\"echo\":").append(input).append("}");

        outMsgLen = response.length();

        // Send 4 bytes of data length
        std::cout.write((char*)&outMsgLen, 4);

        // Send the data
        std::cout << response;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almog: Thank you very much for the reply. Your code works! and with it I figure out the cause of my problem. It is not because of the auto flush. But within my response message, in actually code, I am using a Json libary to prepare the string, the library auto added a "\n" at the end of the string which cause chrome to think that is the first char of the second response I guess. Once I removed that '\n', it works. Also appreciate your comment on the length reading, yours definitely better.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me.