# Java + Native messaging doesn't work good

Tags: google-chrome, native, messaging, npapi

I have a problem with Java application and Google Chrome due to NPAPI deprecation..
Reading some articles and blogs, I've found a "solution" : *Native Messaging*.

But all the examples were made in C++/C#/Python, and for Java there is nothing..
I would like if someone could help me with this..

Here's my schema ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVkk6.jpg)):
Google chrome Extension -> Native messaging -> Java App (jar)

**Problem:**
The extension calls the Java app, the Java app runs but doesn't receive anything and when it returns, nothing comes to extension.

Here's my code:

> **Chrome extension**

**background.js**:

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {

port.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message) { 
 chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  console.log( 'background.js received msg [' + message.text + ']'); 
  console.log( 'port.postMessage({content: "generated by background.js"}); to [' + tabs[0].id + "/" + tabs[0].url + ']');
  chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('cnb.digitalsigning',message,function(response) {
    console.log("Received from native " + response);
  });
 
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {content: "generated by background.js"});
 });
 return true;
  });  
  
port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
  console.log("Background.js Port disconnected");
});

});

  //native messaging
```

**content_script.js**

```js
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  
  if (event.source != window)
    return;

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "DIGITAL_SIGNER_MSG")) {
    console.log("Content script received  from webpage: " + event.data.text);
 console.log('calling port.postMessage(event.data.text); ...' + event.data.text );
 port = chrome.runtime.connect(); 
 port.postMessage({text: event.data.text});
  }
}, false);


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
 alert("receiving response from extension" + response.content );  
});
```

**manifest.json**

```js
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
  "persistent" : true,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]   
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
           "nativeMessaging"
        ]
}
```

> **HTML**

```html
<html>
<script>
function myFunc(){

 console.log('call func');
 window.postMessage({ type: "DIGITAL_SIGNER_MSG", text: "do it, baby!" }, "*");
 console.log('func called');
}


</script>
<body>
<div>Page</div>

<form>
<button  id="caller" onclick="myFunc()">Call Extension</button>
<div id="reponseDiv" style="border: 3px; border-color: blue;">NO RESPONSE LOADED</div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

> **Host**

**installReg.bat**

```js
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\digitalsigning" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0digitalsigning.json" /f

pause
```

**launch.bat**

```js
C:\location\to\Java\jre\bin\java.exe -cp C:\component\target\java.jar com.org.App
pause
```

**digitalsigning.json**

```html
{
  "name": "digitalsigning",
  "description": "digitalsigning",
  "path": "c:\\place\\launch.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://<GOOGLE EXTENSION ID GENERATED>/"
  ]
}
```

The aplication contains a Main that captures the message using `System.in.read` and response to extension using `System.out.write`..

How could I do this communication?
Is this the correct way to start the java app?

Answer (score 0):

At https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617143/865284 you can see how to send data in a proper way. System.in should be the correct way, but by now, i didn't find a way to receive data in java.

Comment: I've tried this with only the System.out.write and that method, but didn't work. The extension 'read' **undefined** :/

Comment: This code-snippet works for me: 
private void testSendData() throws IOException{
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("text", "some text");
 String message = JSONObject.toJSONString(map);
 System.out.write(getBytes(message.length()));
 System.out.println(message);
}

Comment: Joau, did you get success with chrome extension + java? Did you called the jar by the .bat?Could you post the full code?

Comment: I was able to send Message, but didn't manage to receive from chrome. I was calling a .bat file. the path was set absolute.

Comment: Using .bat file it wont work because its then becomes 3rd hand. @joau, please post your solution, there is no documentation for java and chrome. C# worked for me but i need to see how you did in Java. Can you share?

Answer (score 0):

Note also this post, where sent and returned messages are sent successfully using only a few simple lines of code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33113627.  It should make it clear what the basic requirements of returned messages are.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at https://github.com/Cosium/web-native-messaging-host .
It is a java library allowing to turn any JVM application into a Web Native Messaging Host .